# How to export an environment variable from .sh file in zsh?

Tags: shell-script, shell, osx, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have the following shell script

```
TEST=/foopath
export TEST
```

It is in a file called `test.sh` and on which I ran `chmod +x test.sh`

When I run `./test.sh` I expect that I can then execute `echo $TEST` and see the output `/foopath` but I see nothing.

What changes are needed to make the above script export the variable `$TEST` when I run `./test.sh`. Is this a bash vs. zsh difference?

Comment: Assigned variables exports to daughter processes but to parent one. If you like to use vars from script you should use `source` command. `source test.sh`

Comment: There may be a better duplicate (in fact, I'm pretty sure there has been a question specifically about environment variables, but I couldn't find it). The accepted answer addresses this case exactly though.

Answer (score 6):

It's a parent- v. child-shell difference.

When you run `test.sh`, a new shell is started to run it; the variable is exported within that shell. That means the new shell is aware of it, and any of its own children. The parent shell, the one you started `test.sh` from, isn't affected at all (and can't be).

To see the variable in your current shell, you need to source the script instead:

```
. test.sh
```

(with a space between `.` and `test.sh`). This will run `test.sh` without starting a new shell.